# How to sum only same line specific column is true

Tags: excel, excel-formula

```
  | A                      | B
1 | Boolean                | number |
2 | TRUE                   | 0
3 | FALSE                  | 1
4 | TRUE                   | 1
5 | FALSE                  | 1
- - - - - - - - -
6 | 2 COUNTIF(A2:A5,TRUE)  | ?
```

B6 How to sum only same line specific column (A) is true
   e.g  A2, A4 is true so B2 + B4

```
=SUMIF(B2:B5,A2:A5=TRUE)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're close: `=SUMIF(A2:A5,TRUE,B2:B5)`